# validate of input when blur. hope click dropdown doesn't trigger blur as validate not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

see the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/w6xzkpm457

think Validate as Form from third part library! i want to validate input when blur, however when click dropdown(autocomplete customized by me), it trigger blur and validate input when change event doesn't happen and lead to error verification! anyone can help?